# Can't use search function

Tags: python

Trying to run a basic search program with Python (beginner level). All other options work (N, Q) but when trying to select S, I receive a nameerror for "plateNum" as not being defined. Even when entering new information, then trying to recall it, it won't allow me to search for the already inputted information.

```
#mainMenu Function
def displayMainMenu():
    print("\nMAIN MENU")
    print("(S) Search vehicle by license plate")
    print("(N) Add new vehicle")
    print("(Q) Quit")


def searchPlate(plateNum, choice):
    plateNum = input("Enter 7-DIGIT license plate number: ")
    try:
        file = open(plateNum + " data.txt", "r")
        DataList = file.readlines()
        file.close()
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("\nContact not found!\n")
    else:
        print("(P)late Number")
        print("(Ma)ke")
        print("(Mo)del")
        print("(Y)ear")
        print("(C)olor")
        print("(I)All information")
        choice = input(">> ").upper()
        print("\n" + plateNum)
        if choice == "Ma":
            print(DataList[0])
        if choice == "Mo":
            print(DataList[1])
        if choice == "Y":
            print(DataList[2])
        if choice == "C":
            print(DataList[3])
        if choice == "I":
            print(DataList[0])
            print(DataList[1])
            print(DataList[2])
            print(DataList[3])

                
#AddVehicle function
def newVehicle():
    newPlate = input("Enter license plate of vehicle: ")
    newMake = input("Enter Make of vehicle: ")
    newModel = input("Enter model of vehicle: ")
    newYear = input("Enter year of vehicle: ")
    newColor = input("Enter color(s) of vehicle: ")
    newList = [newPlate + "\n", newMake + "\n", newModel + "\n", newYear + "\n", newColor + "\n"]
    file = open(newPlate + " data.txt", "w")
    file.writelines(newList)
    file.close()
    print("Vehicle Successfully Saved")

#choice 
choice = ""
while choice != "Q":
    displayMainMenu()
    choice = input(">> ").upper()
    if choice == "S":
        searchPlate(plateNum,choice)
    if choice == "N":
        newVehicle()
else:
    print("Have a nice day!")
```

Comment: Well, at the point in the code where `searchPlate` is called there is no variable named `plateNum`.

Comment: You are using an undefined name `plateNum` when you *call* the function. Neither argument actually gets used in the function, as `choice` is ignored and `plateNum` is immediately replaced by a new input.

Answer (score 0):

```py
while choice != "Q":
    displayMainMenu()
    choice = input(">> ").upper()
    if choice == "S":
        searchPlate(plateNum,choice)
```

`platenum` isn't defined there in the global scope, that's why you're getting the error. Just change it to

```py
plateNum = ""
while choice != "Q":
    displayMainMenu()
    choice = input(">> ").upper()
    if choice == "S":
        searchPlate(plateNum,choice)
```

or, remove `plateNum` from the arguments.

Answer (score 0):

You defined `searchPlate` to take a plate number as an argument, but then you

- try to use an undefined variable of the same name to provide that argument, and
- you immediately replace whatever value might be passed with a new input.

You do the same thing with `choice`; that name is at least defined when you call `searchPlate`, but you don't need to pass its value to the function.

Replace the definition of `searchPlate` with

```
def searchPlate(plateNum):
    try:
        file = open(plateNum + " data.txt", "r")
        DataList = file.readlines()
        file.close()
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("\nContact not found!\n")
    else:
        ...
```

then replace its use with something like

```
if choice == "S":
    x = input("Enter 7-DIGIT license plate number: ")
    searchPlate(x)
```